# Textblock displaying "..." instead of "-" when Width="Auto"

Tags: wpf, text, textblock

I have a Textblock that shows 3 Dots instead of a Minus when Width is set to Auto. The Font is Arial and the `FontSize` is 20. The Width during Runtime is 7.

```
<:TextBlock 
    x:Name="LabelText" 
    MaxHeight="50" 
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="5,0,0,0" 
    Style="{StaticResource TextLabelFontStyle}" 
    Width="Auto" />
```

**Anyone know why i dont see the Minus?**

Comment: i dont understand...you have hyphen in the end of string which is replace by dots, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, instead of - i see ... That happens normally if the Text is to long to fit in the Textbox.

Comment: Remove TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  and see the result

Comment: I can try but this cant be the solution because i want to have this

Comment: dots are coming due to this... also can you share where are you placing this textblock... its parent xaml etc

Comment: The Textblocks parent is a grid where the Width is also set to Auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be some strange TextBlock behaviour. I changed the  HorizontalAlignment="Left" to  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and added TextAlignment="Left". Now it wokrks properly.

Answer (score 2):

@Bulli, what nit was saying in his comment is that those 3 dots are added to the end of a `TextBlock` when the text *does not completely fit* into the allowed space *when you use a `TextTrimming` value of `CharacterEllipsis`*.

So you have two possible solutions... the first is to follow nit's advice and remove that property from your `TextBlock`. As you said that you don't want to do that, the only other option is to make your `TextBlock` wider so that the text *will* fit inside.

Comment: I understand what he mean but the problem is that my Textblock can have a maximum width of 600 when its needed. But for some reason the Textblock dont reserve enough Width to show the Minus. Instead the 3 Dots are displayed which are much wider than the minus. Dont make sense...

Comment: If you provide *all* of the relevant code, we can test it for you. Just hard code your text string into the `Text` property and provide your `TextLabelFontStyle Style` and the container that imposes the 600 pixel limit. Please add this into your question and *not* into the comments section as it will be clearer and more people will see it there.